# Photo upload on React Native Android produce Type Error Network Error

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, multipartform-data

I'm executing a photo upload using the fetch API and I keep receiving `Type Error Network Request Error`. I receive the same error on the emulator and a device. I'm using react-native-image-crop-picker as the source for the photo upload data. Any thoughts?

```
const handlePhotoUpload =  async (image: any, token: string) => {

      const { path, filename, mime } = image;

      const uri = path.replace("file://", "")
      const file = {
        uri,            
        type: mime,           
        name: filename             
      };

      const body = new FormData()
      body.append('file', file)

      const config = {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
        body
      };

      return await fetch(`${<API URL>}/user/photo`, config)

}
```

Comment: Check your internet connection and if server URL is accessible from the device. Also attach full stack trace of the error.

Comment: What doesn't make sense is the fact that I'm using the same server URL for other API calls.

Comment: What is `<API URL>` ? Do you have these variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I faced same issue, it happens in Android, but works well in IOS. I
> guess this issue about Flipper Network.

**For while, I commented**
initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())

in this file
**/android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java**

Answer (score 1):

The below steps helped me resolve the same issue. Just in case helps,

1. In android/app/src/main/java/com/{yourProject}/MainApplication.java
   comment the below line :

   ```
   initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
   ```
2. In android/app/src/debug/java/com/{yourProject}/ReactNativeFlipper.java
   comment in line 43 :

   ```
   builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
   ```
3. Code for image upload :

   ```
   var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('UserId', 'abc@abc.com');
      formData.append('VisitId', '28596');
      formData.append('EvidenceCapturedDate', '09/10/2019 13:28:20');
      formData.append('EvidenceCategory', 'Before');
      formData.append('EvidenceImage', {
        uri: Platform.OS === 'android' ? `file:///${path}` : `/private${path}`,
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
      });
      axios({
        url: UrlString.BaseUrl + UrlString.imageUpload,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle success******');
          console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          console.log('*****handle failure******');
          console.log(response);
        });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I know its late to reply but helplfull for others

do following steps

In your project directory click android folder and then open gradle.properties and change fliper version to this

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.47.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the way you send it is Android, the way is wrong.

**The correct uri is:**

```js
uri: Platform.OS === "android" ? path : path.replace("file://", "")
```

Comment: i removed the file:/// but i got networ Error

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara Network errors are different from paths.